# Handling denied camera permissions in an iOS App Clip

Tags: ios, swiftui, apple-appclips

My iOS app depends on having camera access. For the main app, I prompt the user to grant camera access when the app launches for the first time. If the user denies this request, I show a screen telling them to go to their settings and grant camera access there. This works fine

For my app clip however, if the user denies the initial prompt, it seem like they can never grant camera access to the clip. There is no settings section for the app clip and I can't figure out any other way to re-prompt them. The app is just not functional after this

How should I handle this case for my app clip? Is there something I can tell the user to do in order to grant camera access (or other permissions) to my app clip after they initially denyied it?

The only solution I've come up with so far is to tell the user to install the main app

Comment: I should note that the app does show a screen explaining why camera access is needed before showing the system prompt. I don't expect many users to get into this state but the few that do will be stuck with a completely broken experience

Comment: After reading [Learn More About App Clips](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212238) and having a look at my phone, it appears that the user should be able to change the settings by going to the Settings app and looking under "Privacy -> Camera -> App Clip" (I don't have any app clips installed so, that's as deep as I got)

Comment: Oh nice! I confirmed that works but it is definitely well hidden. Also I don't think  can open that settings page programmatically:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66678346/ios-app-clip-opensettingsurlstring-app-settings 

Want to post this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [Learn More About App Clips](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212238) and having a look at my phone, it appears that the user should be able to change the settings by going to the Settings app and looking under `Privacy -> Camera -> App Clip` (I don't have any app clips installed so, that's as deep as I got)

Comment: Can confirm, this works. But is there a way to open that page automatically?

Comment: No, I doubt you can open those settings from within App, maybe one day :P